# Responsive Sidebar css

Tags: css

I am making a responsive sidebar and I encountered some problem:

When I hover over the button, the sidebar will appear.

the sidebar did not appear as expected when I hovered over the button. I could not figure out why it would not display again.
Thanks for the help.

Additional Pic of website
[not hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GUPd.png)

expected:
[hovered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQsLW.png)

```css
.sidebar {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: var(--SIDE);
  height: 100%;
  animation: showMenu 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  transform-origin: left center;
  display: none;
}

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-icon,
.menu-icon::before,
.menu-icon::after {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu-icon::before,
.menu-icon::after {
  content: "";
}

.menu-icon::before {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.menu-icon::after {
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .menu-icon {
  background-color: transparent;
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .menu-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .menu-icon::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .sidebar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <button class="button"><div class="menu-icon"></div></button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <aside>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Website A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Website B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Website C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Website D</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Website E</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<div>` cannot be the child of `<button>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use of is:() in css. You can learn more about it here [MDN Reference: is:()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

In your use case, it will be better if you use javascript if you are not going to keep the elements as adjacent children.

However, you can do it with pure css also with a little change in html markup:

```css
.sidebar {
  /*   z-index: 1; */
  position: absolute; /* Absolute so that it doesn't display in the header and you can display it on the screen as an overlay. */
  margin-top: 60px;
  background: var(--SIDE);
  height: 100%;
  animation: showMenu 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
  transform-origin: left center;
  display: none;
}

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-icon,
.menu-icon::before,
.menu-icon::after {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu-icon::before,
.menu-icon::after {
  content: "";
}

.menu-icon::before {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.menu-icon::after {
  transform: translateY(10px);
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .menu-icon {
  background-color: transparent;
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .menu-icon::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

:is(.button:hover, .button:focus) .menu-icon::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .button:hover+aside .sidebar {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <button class="button"><div class="menu-icon"></div></button>
      <aside>
        <div class="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Website A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Website B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Website C</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Website D</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Website E</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: You are working with the same invalid HTML he supplied.

Comment: @Rob it's not exactly same. i have kept it as much similar so that he can understand and relate it better to his own case. i have moved the aside to be an adjacent children to the button so that we can use css' + combinator. It has position: absolute in css so that it is displayed as an overlay on the screen and not mess up the header. as for the div within the button, that is unrelated to this question. hence, i did not change it.